# Sorting an array using a C-style comparator

Tags: c++, std

I need to implement a sort function that will be called from C. The interface looks like this (and, as much as I or anyone else would like to change it, I can't):

```
typedef int (*comparator )(const void*, const void*, void*);
void c_sort(void* ptr, long count, long size, ComparatorFunc comp, void* userData);
```

I can use C++ to implement this function, but I cannot change the interface. I can see three things to do:

1. Write my own sort function. This sounds like a bad idea, since then we're responsible for maintaining it, and it will be difficult to implement something as well as the implementation in either the C or C++ standard library without spending three weeks or more on it.
2. Call qsort. The problem here is that the comparator takes a void* as the third argument, which is basically anything the caller wants to pass in to help implement the comparator.
3. Use std::sort and a comparator wrapper around the function pointer. This is my favoritest option, because it seems easier than the other three.

In addition, whatever implementation I settle on needs to be thread-safe, so I can't assign some static global to the pointer to the userData and use that global to pass the userData to the comparator.

Anyway, assuming number 3 is where I would like to go (though I'm open to other options), here's my question: I can pretty easily set up a functor that wraps the function pointer, but I can't figure out what to cast the void* pointer to so that I can call sort.

```
template<typename T>
class ComparatorWrapper
{
public:
  ComparatorWrapper(ComparatorFunc comparator, void* userData)
    : comparator_(comparator),
      userData_(userData)
  { }

  bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b)
  {
    return comparator_(
      reinterpret_cast<void*>(&a),
      reinterpret_cast<void*>(&b),
      context) < 0;
  }

private:
  ComparatorFunc comparator_;
  void* userData_;
};
```

And the call to the sort should look something like this:

```
T* foo = reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr);
ComparatorWrapper<T> wrapper(comparator, userData);
std::sort(foo, foo+count, wrapper);
```

The problem is that I don't know what `T` should be. The only thing I know is that `sizeof(T) == size`. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: why not use thread local storage

Comment: I'm not recommending to use it, just for your info, you can use thread-local storage with qsort for thread-safety

Comment: The thread-local storage is interesting. How much overhead does accessing and assigning to thread-local is there in general on Wintel systems?

Comment: depends on units you'd like to measure in :) in general, it's quite expensive